# Angular 2: use *ngIf with async

Tags: angular, typescript

There are two buttons Login and Logout. Initially only Login button is visible. But after authentication, the Login button should change to Logout button.
But at me it why that does not work, how can I fix it?

html:

```
<div *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Login
    </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="logOut()">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {

  signInUser = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  @Output() onFormResult = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(protected authService:AuthService, private router:Router) {

   }


  ngOnInit() {
  }


  logOut(){
    this.authService.logOutUser().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/info']));
  }

  onSignInSubmit(){

    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');

    this.authService.logInUser(this.signInUser).subscribe(

        res => {
          if(res.status == 200){
            // loginForm.resetForm();
            this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: true, res});
            this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
          }
        },

        err => {
          console.log('err:', err);
          // loginForm.resetForm();
          this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: false, err});
        }
    )

  }

}
```

Comment: What is it that does not work?

Comment: Can you provide your component.ts file?

Comment: Login button does not change to Logout button after authentication

Comment: @Jack, everything

Comment: Why do you need async here? I don't think it should be required

Comment: use `<div *ngIf="!authService.userSignedIn$">` and `<div *ngIf="authService.userSignedIn$">`

Comment: without `async` you will have to add a `subscription` in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`

```
userSignedIn$:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use ngIf-else with ng-template like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async); else logout">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Login
    </button>
</div>
<ng-template #logout>
<div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="logOut()">Logout</button>
</div>
</ng-template>
```